# Bot Framework: In FormBuilder Confirmation method, if user responds as "No" then bot should quit the form

Tags: botframework, formbuilder

I have below code in Bot Framework app, when bot asks confirmation from the user and the user responds with "No", then the built-in step for modifying form parameters get executes. like "Do you want to change" with parameters name and value. What I want to do is when the user responds with "No" then bot should quit the form processing.

```
public static IForm<FlightBooking> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<FlightBooking>().Message("Tell me meeting details!")
    .Field(nameof(title))
    .Confirm(async (state) =>
     {
       return new PromptAttribute(new TemplateAttribute(TemplateUsage.Confirmation, "Do you really want to continue?")); 
     })
    .Build();
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the code from your FlightBooking class?

Comment: The code is from FlightBooking class itself, What exactly you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added one more field in form flow as "confirmation", which will ask you the confirmation and in return, we will get either Yes/No.